# How can I set an external variable to nil inside a method?

Tags: delphi, reference, delphi-7, null, tthread

I'd like to subclass `TThread` in order to have a thread class that, when `FreeOnTerminate = True`, sets to `nil` its reference variable. 
In other words, I want do do something like this:

```
TFreeAndNilThread = class(TThread)
private
  FReferenceObj: TFreeAndNilThread;  //??  // <-- here I'm holding the reference to myself
protected
  procedure Execute;
  procedure DoTerminate; override;  // <-- here I'll set FReferenceObj to nil after inherited (only if FreeAndNil = True)
public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; var ReferenceObj); reintroduce;  <-- untyped param like FreeAndNil and TApplication.CreateForm ??
end;
```

The consumer code should be like this:

```
var
  MyThread: TFreeAndNilThread;

begin
  MyThread := TFreeAndNilThread.Create(True, MyThread);
  MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  MyThread.Resume;
end;
```

...and then I could safely test for `Assigned(MyThread)`.

I see how `FreeAndNil` manages to set a reference object passed by untyped param to `nil`, but it does this locally. 
In my case I should "save" it to a class field (`FReferenceObj`) and make it nil in another place (`DoTerminate`).

How can I correctly pass, store and retrieve it? 
I can think of passing and storing the address of MyThread instead of MyThread itself, but I hope there is a more elegant way.

Thank you!

Comment: I must be missing something.  What is wrong with hooking `OnTerminate` and setting `MyThread := nil` ? (or removing the entry from a thread list, for that matter)

Comment: OnTerminate is executed in the main thread because is called Synchronized  (see the standard implementation of `DoTerminate`.

Comment: @yankee But you do need to make sure that the code that sets the reference to `nil` is executed in the same thread that accesses that reference.

Comment: ... which is (normally) the main thread.

Comment: @Hugh I see your point, and this is, in fact, the actual behaviour of my threads. But I tried to better explain the situation in the comments of the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a pointer to the variable.

```
type
  TFreeAndNilThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FReferenceObj: ^TFreeAndNilThread;
  end;
```

Then you need to pass in the reference in the constructor:

```
type
  TFreeAndNilThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FReferenceObj: ^TFreeAndNilThread;
  public
    constructor Create(var ReferenceObj: TFreeAndNilThread);
  end;
```

Then you can implement it like this:

```
constructor TFreeAndNilThread.Create(var ReferenceObj: TFreeAndNilThread);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FReferenceObj := @ReferenceObj;
end;
```

When the thread dies you set the reference to `nil` like this:

```
ReferenceObj^ := nil;
```

For convenience, since you'd likely treat this as a base class from which you derive other classes, you may prefer to make the parameter to the constructor untyped. You can just do that without making other changes to the code. When you do so the constructor looks like this:

```
constructor Create(var ReferenceObj);
```

---

This will only do you good if the code that sets the reference to `nil` is in the same thread as all other code that attempts to reference `MyThread`. Otherwise you will have a race condition.

I'm fairly sure that your idea is not the solution to your problem. However, the above does show you how to take a reference to a variable, which is what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much. As for the race  condition, The test for `Assigned(MyThread)` is done in the main thread just to make sure that `MyThread` has finished executing: I don use `MyThread` after that test, so (if i'm not missing something) there shouldn't be a race condition.

Comment: In that case you can just do what Hugh suggested I believe.

Comment: Maybe you are right about the initial idea not being the real solution, but I foud out that 1) Waiting for thread termination with a wait function and 2) handling OnTerminate event are mutually exclusive because otherwise a deadlock is assured. I'd like to wait for thread termination in a way that ensures a) a timeout, b) not freezing the GUI and c) the execution of OnTerminate if it is implemented, but don't want to force the creation of such handler if not needed. So I imagined a sort of `while (Assigned(MyThread)) and (not TimeoutExpired) do Application.ProcessMessages;`

Comment: Hmm, busy wait. Not very keen on that. Frankly if you are going to wait on your thread, why are you making it `FreeOnTerminate`. That's for threads that you fire off and forget about. If you want to interact with it, don't make it `FreeOnTerminate`.

Comment: You are right again. I was trying not to do too many modifications to code written by others, but I realize that "half-solutions" are worse than no-solutions. The real solution is to refactor all that code and take the right approach for each case (there are many threads that behave differently).

Comment: `TThread.WaitFor()` and `TThread.OnTerminate` are not mutually exclusive and do not cause a deadlock when used together. `OnTerminate` is triggered via `TThread.Synchronize()`, and `WaitFor()` processes `Synchronize()` requests while it is waiting. On the other hand, `FreeOnTerminate=True` and `WaitFor()` do not work together. When the thread terminates and frees itself, `WaitFor()` crashes.